# Is Java List of multiple types possible

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, java-8

yesterday I stumbled upon some strange Java/Spring/IntelliJ behavior that I was not able to explain.

This is a Spring Boot application made with jdk1.8.0_152.

I ran this simple SQL to fill my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_ORGANIZATION
(
    ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TEST_ORGANIZATION (ID, NAME) VALUES ('1', 'test1');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORGANIZATION (ID, NAME) VALUES ('2', 'test2');
```

Here's my Entity class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class TestOrganization {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

And my JPA Repository:

```
public interface TestOrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<TestOrganization, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new map(id as key, name as value) FROM TestOrganization")
    List<Map<String, String>> findAllAndMapById();
}
```

And this is where things get confusing.
I've written a simple unit test to check for the values, but turns out it fails on second assert:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetDocumentByName() {
    List<String> values = testOrganizationRepository.findAllAndMapById()
            .stream()
            .flatMap( m -> m.values().stream() )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() );

    assertThat( values ).isNotEmpty();
    assertThat( values ).allMatch( n -> n instanceof String );
}
```

When debugging with IntelliJ, it shows *values* like this:

[image]

How is this possible? Why am I able to have Long values within a List of String?

Also:

```
 values.add(1L) // fails to compile
 values.get(0).getClass().name // returns java.lang.String
 values.get(1).getClass().name // returns java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible because of type erasure in Java. In short, this means that in the runtime Java doesn't know about your generic type, so any `List` object operates with `Object` type. The generics are made to have the compile-type safety.
But you can read about type erasure in more details, for example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure).

The same behavior you can emulate by yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    addToList(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static void addToList(List list) {
    list.add(1L);
    list.add(42);
    list.add("String");
    list.add(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {}
    });
}
```

This code works fine as long as you don't try to operate with the list entries as a Strings. But when you add something like:

```
for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You will get `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

So in compile time, you work with `List<String>`, but in the runtime, Java only knows about `List`.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I forgot about type erasure. Hoped I finally managed to break Java :D

Comment: @PatrykKrawczyk no problems! Always glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, here is small example

```
public static void main(String args) {
        List objects = new ArrayList();
        objects.add("string");
        objects.add(1L);

        List<String> onlyStrings = objects;

    }
```

you can cast your non generic list to List if you wish so (you get bunch of compiler warnings).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List a = new ArrayList();
    a.add("a");
    a.add(1L);

    List<String> b = new ArrayList(a);

    System.out.println(b);
}
```

This outputs

```
[a, 1]
```

The above is legal, as java performs type erasure, thus discarding the element type information at runtime. This means that every List is essentially a List and can contain multiple class instances.

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

gets converted to

```
public interface List extends Collection
```

at compile time.

If E was bound, i.e. E extends MyClass, it would be converted to MyClass.

In your case, you are instantiating a map for every row, without type bounds, you are flatmapping it and then collecting it to a List, which is effectively the same as my example, and thus, legal.